# React Native release a letter is missing

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I watched a tutorial about React Native on YouTube.

I have built a simple stopper app. (Android) The problem is, in the release build, one of the letters is missing. I tried to build another simple app with just having "Hello" and in the release build in my phone instead of showing "Hello" I get "Hell".

Pictures:

Development build using Nexus 6 (AVD):

[image]

Release build with LG G4 (physical):

[image]

I don't know why this is happening. I appreciate any advice and help.

Edit: index.android.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

class flexbox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.header]}>
          <View style={[styles.timeWrapper]}>
            <Text style={styles.timer}>00:00.00</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.buttonWrapper]}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('Start')} underlayColor="#2ecc71" style={[styles.button, styles.startButton]}>
              <Text>Start</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('Lap')} underlayColor="#1abc9c" style={[styles.button, styles.lapButton]}>
              <Text>Lap</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.footer]}>
          <Text>Laps</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1
  },
  footer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  timeWrapper: {
    flex: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  timer: {
    fontSize: 60,
    color: 'black'
  },
  button: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  startButton: {
    borderColor: '#2ecc71'
  },
  lapButton: {
    borderColor: '#1abc9c'
  }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('flexbox', () => flexbox)
```

Comment: Sometimes devices behave differently.. can you try both release and debug on the same device and see if it happens? also providing some code can help us identify the problem

Comment: I will try to install debug on my phone.

Comment: With ADB right?

Comment: yes.
adb install -r "path/to/app.apk"

Comment: I see "La" also on debug (LG G4, ADB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't supplied any code, but I'm guessing you have created a view with exact width and height, and in order to have the text in the middle, you added padding.

Here's an example of a working circle with text:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.circle}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  circle: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 3,
  }
});
```

Or see example in [sketch](https://sketch.expo.io/HJYkpEN3e)

Comment: I've supplied an example. See in my question.

Comment: Can you please try to add style to your text:
<Text style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', textAlign: 'center'}}>Start</Text>

Comment: Thank you, that really helped.